# Storing token in client object vs in keychain and recovering each time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, afnetworking, keychain

From a security perspective with iOS, what is a better idea?

- With AFNetworking, I can create a subclass of AFHTTPClient and have one instance of that class (like [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) be used whenever I need to make a network request. I could then set the `token` property of that object when the user logs in and I receive a token, and now the object has a token and I can forget about it and use it without needing to provide a token again in future uses of the object. Like in my example: `[AFInstapaperClient sharedClient].token = ...`
- Use the keychain. Request the token from the keychain each time, provide it, then destroy the token property of the AFHTTPClient subclass.

Which would be a better idea? And if the second, would I destroy it just by setting it to nil?

Answer (score 0):

Go with option 1.

To keep the login alive between runs of the app, store the token in the keychain. Just load the token back (and check validity) when the app starts.